# Android: padding left a bitmap with white color

Tags: java, android, colors, bitmap, padding

How to set all white the 10 rows on the left side of a Bitmap?
I'v got a Bitmap that has to be padded on the left side. I thought i can create a new image iterate on the old one getpixel for each position and setpixel on the new one (white or colored) than return the new bitmap...is this wrong?
Any suggestion? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 32):

You can instead create a new Bitmap with the extra padding number of pixels.
Set this as the canvas bitmap and Color the entire image with the required color and then copy your bitmap.

```
public Bitmap pad(Bitmap Src, int padding_x, int padding_y) {
    Bitmap outputimage = Bitmap.createBitmap(Src.getWidth() + padding_x,Src.getHeight() + padding_y, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas can = new Canvas(outputimage);
    can.drawARGB(FF,FF,FF,FF); //This represents White color
    can.drawBitmap(Src, padding_x, padding_y, null);
    return outputimage;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! thanks..just one more question..for x-offset you mean the first pixel left after padding?

Comment: Lets say i have a bitmap with dimentions (w256, h104), wil this be able to make this image (w256, h128) by adding white spaces on top and bottom evenly without stretching the image?

Comment: Nice but it only add pixcels to top and left side of bitmap. nothing found for all 4 sides(top,left,right,bottom).

Comment: @RahulSharma I just did this to give padding from all side. Hope it will help someone.  Bitmap outputimage = Bitmap.createBitmap(Src.getWidth() + padding_x,Src.getHeight() + padding_y, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas can = new Canvas(outputimage);
        can.drawBitmap(Src, padding_x, padding_y, null);

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(outputimage.getWidth()+padding_x, outputimage.getHeight() + padding_y, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
        canvas.drawBitmap(outputimage, 0, 0, null);      return output;

Answer (score 9):

```
public Bitmap addPaddingTopForBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int paddingTop) {
    Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight() + paddingTop, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(outputBitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, paddingTop, null);
    return outputBitmap;
}

public Bitmap addPaddingBottomForBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int paddingBottom) {
    Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight() + paddingBottom, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(outputBitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    return outputBitmap;
}


public Bitmap addPaddingRightForBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int paddingRight) {
    Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth() + paddingRight, bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(outputBitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    return outputBitmap;
}

public Bitmap addPaddingLeftForBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int paddingLeft) {
    Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth() + paddingLeft, bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(outputBitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, paddingLeft, 0, null);
    return outputBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much man. Your functions are easy to use. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a kotlin extension function with RxJava to get it done. I haven't tested completely but based combined the previous answers to get something

```
fun Bitmap.pad(top: Float = 0F, bottom: Float = 0F, left: Float = 0F, right: Float = 0F): Single<Bitmap> {
    return Single.create<Bitmap> { emitter ->
        val output = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            (width + left + right).toInt(),
            (height + top + bottom).toInt(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        )
        val canvas = Canvas(output)

        canvas.drawBitmap(this, left, top, null)

        emitter.onSuccess(output)
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
}
```

I think the coroutine version would simply be

```
suspend fun Bitmap.pad(top: Float = 0F, bottom: Float = 0F, left: Float = 0F, right: Float = 0F): Bitmap {
    val output = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        (width + left + right).toInt(),
        (height + top + bottom).toInt(),
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )
    val canvas = Canvas(output)

    canvas.drawBitmap(this, left, top, null)

    return output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did this to give padding from all side. Hope it will help someone.
Combination of  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44060669/6480433 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/6957333/6480433 these answer.

```
Bitmap outputimage = Bitmap.createBitmap(Src.getWidth() + padding_x,Src.getHeight() + padding_y, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas can = new Canvas(outputimage);
        can.drawBitmap(Src, padding_x, padding_y, null);

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(outputimage.getWidth()+padding_x, outputimage.getHeight() + padding_y, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
        canvas.drawBitmap(outputimage, 0, 0, null);    
  return output;
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html

methods you might want to use are: getHeight() then you know how many pixels to set and iterate over 10 columns

and setRGB (int x, int y, int RGB) to set the pixel

Comment: does this works on android? i'v got a Bitmap (android class) image..ho to switch to BufferedImage? thanks!